# Disable banner View in some fragment

Tags: android, view, interface, fragment

I have defined a custom banner in my activity. My project has this kind of structure:

-Activity: Fragment1, **Fragment2**, Fragment3

-**Fragment2**: **Fragment4**, Fragment5

So, for example, to swipe from Fragment2 to Fragment4 I replace the fragment directly from Fragment2.

Now, whenever user click on Fragment4 I want the banner defined inside the main activity

```
        AdView mAdView = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.adView);
```

To become **invisible**

How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 1):

I Just got the best way to do this so now think of you need to hide admob ad which is generated in MainActivity so when you are going to call fragment just set the visibility gone in mainactivity.

Let me know if you have any issue.

```
 case R.id.nav_frag1:
                fragment = new Fragment1();
                mAdView = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.adView);
                mAdView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                title = getString(R.string.title_frag1);
                break;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way (but by far not the easiest) is to use [DataBinding](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/index.html) and pass the layout of each Fragment a boolean value which tells it weather or not this banner should be visible.
Then in your layout you can do something like:

```
<layout ... >
   <data>
    <import type="android.view.View"/>
    <variable name="showBanner" type="boolean" />
   </data>
   ...
   <BannerView
      ...
      android:visibility='@{showBanner ? View.VISIBLE : View.INVISIBLE}'
      ...
   />
   ...
</layout>
```

Comment: Isn't there any other way? Like interface my button from main activity?

Comment: That depends on your implementation. Are you using a ViewPager to change between fragments?